# Automating converting special characters into html entities. Can anyone id this character?

Tags: html, character, html-entities

What is this character †
Is there anyway to convert such characters automatically to their html entities? I use DreamWeaver and Notepad++. I've tried [this site](http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/) but it's no where near powerful enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Tis a "dagger":

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2020/index.htm

HTML entity is `&#8224;`.

Answer (score 8):

I used the HTML plugin for notepad++. If you go to plugins > plugins manager and open it and select the HTML plugin. From then on you can select the text you're interested in then go to plugins>html tags> decode or encode.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write your own conversion table.

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dreamweaver you can write in a & in the code view and it opens a nifty little window which lets you scroll trough entities in a list; also in the design view it automatically converts input to it's entity by default in the code.

This character is

```
&dagger;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=%E2%98%A3&.submit=Submit%20Query) simply takes a character and gives you its unicode, utf-8 representation and html entity.